# Why I can't retrieve all data given an ID? php-codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to retrieve data from datbase given an ID number.

Controller: 
**Usuario.php**

```
  public function seleccionar_por_id_estado(){
    $id_estado = $this->input->post('id_estado');
    $result = $this->usuario_m->ver_datos_por_id($id_estado);
        $data['result'] = $result;
        $this->load->view('paginas/administrar_usuarios', $data);
    }
```

My Model
**usuario_m.php**

```
public function ver_datos_por_id($id_estado){
    $condicion = "estado =" . "'". $id_estado ."'";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    $this->db->where($condicion);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

My View
**administrar_usuarios.php**

```
<form action="usuario/seleccionar_por_id_estado">
    <div class="content well">
            <label>Ver por:
                <select id="id_estado">
                    <option>Activo</option>
                    <option>Inactivo</option>
                </select>
                <?php
                foreach ($result as $u){?>
                    <?php echo $u->usuario;?> <br>
                <?php } ?>
            </form>
```

The error that I'm getting is that the var $result is not defined.
Could you help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: try to print your variable `$result` variable before loading the view that you are getting result or not.

Comment: try to print $result inyour controller or echo the value of $condicion in your model

Answer (score 0):

In your model.Set condition inside `$this->db->where()` like this

```
<?php
public function ver_datos_por_id($id_estado){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    $this->db->where('estado',$id_estado);//set your condition  here
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**OR**  use `$this->db->get_where`

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('usuarios',array('estado'=>$id_estado));
return $query->result();
```

For more see docs [Codeigniter Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

**UPDATE**

Controller:

```
 public function seleccionar_por_id_estado(){
    $id_estado = $this->input->post('id_estado');
    $data['result'] = $this->usuario_m->ver_datos_por_id($id_estado);
    $this->load->view('paginas/administrar_usuarios', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I still having the "Undefined variable: result" :(

Comment: check where is your view..inside subfolder paginas or not?

Comment: and don;t forget to load your model in controller.

Comment: Yes @Hek.. my view is inside paginas folder... and I added $this->load->model('usuario_m'); in my controller. :(

Comment: in controller `print_r($result)` what is output?

Comment: in model return `return $query->row();` and in view remove `foreach` and use `<?php echo $result->usuario;?> `.hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in your where condition in model.
use this query

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('usuarios', array('column name of your table' => $condicion));
```

Answer (score -1):

First, I'd check to be certain that `$id_estado` isn't empty.

Another possible problem is that Codeigniter **really** wants you to capitalize class and file names. I'd try renaming the model to 'Usuario_m.php', name the class in the model Usuario_m, and then load it by calling `$this->load->model('Usuario_m);` (looks like you forgot to load the model too) and then finally call the model function like this:

```
$result = $this->Usuario_m->ver_datos_por_id($id_estado);
```

**Update**
Your where() parameters are wrong too. Your entire function in the model can be just this:

```
public function ver_datos_por_id($id_estado){ 
   return $this->db->get_where('usurarios', array('estado' =>$id_estado)->result(); 
}
```

The get_where function combines get() and where(), chooses the table with the first parameter (so you don't need $this->db->from('usuarios');)